# Существует ли лимит на объем данных приложения на Android?

Tags: android

В Android данные приложений, устанавливаемых пользователем, хранятся в подкаталогах /data/data. Существуют ли лимит/quot'ы на объем хранилища для приложения? (например, чтобы оно не могло "съесть" все свободное место на разделе, так что его не осталось для других приложений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации я явных цифр не нашел. Пишут что может быть ограничено.
На просторах интернета находил разные цифры для разных версий. 3.5G но опять же без ссылки на доки.

```
class DeviceMemory(val context: Context) {
   val internalStorageSpace: String
    get() {
        val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePathr)
        val result= statFs.blockCountLong * statFs.blockSizeLong
        return Formatter.formatFileSize(context, result)
    }

  val internalFreeSpace: String
    get() {
        val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath)
        val   result= statFs.availableBlocksLong * statFs.blockSizeLong
        return Formatter.formatFileSize(context, result)
    }

 val internalUsedSpace: String
    get() {
        val statFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath)
        val total =
            statFs.blockCountLong * statFs.blockSizeLong
        val free =
            statFs.availableBlocksLong * statFs.blockSizeLong
        val   result=  total - free
        return Formatter.formatFileSize(context, result)
    }
```

}

Написал простенький класс он, на моем телефоне(andoid 10) показал что мне доступно 95гигов.  Это все свободное место.

========UPDATE=========================================================
Написал маленькую функцию которая пишет случайный текст файл, результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В настройках телефона показывает, что осталось 9М
Size internalFreeSpace 9,51 МБ
Итого в целом программа может получить все доступное место, но судя по документации, могут быть ограничения в разных версиях и вендорах.
Так же когда то читал, но немогу сейча найти ссылки, что  на некоторых версиях андроид, ты мог использовать все место, но так чтоб остаток был не менее(200мб,500мб)

Comment: Так вроде это приложение и проверяет количество свободного места. Никто не гарантирует, что все это место дадут занять.

Comment: @tosh17, а можете заодно попробовать записать файл размером с доступное место (95Г)?

Comment: @n00b1am ограничение на файл и доступное место это разные вещи. размер одного максимального файла приблизительно 4гб

Comment: @tosh17, Ну ок, а если записать 95 / 4 файлов? Еще момент: 4GB лимит это видимо про SD-карту, так как для /data используется ext4,у которой max file size 16TB.

Comment: @n00b1am  да, про размер файла, обманул, не то вспомнил :), создание файла запустил, как доделается обновлю ответ. пока 50G полет нормальный

Comment: @tosh17, ок, спс за помощь! :)